# difference between file.write() and file.writelines() Python

Tags: python

my understanding is `file.write()` takes `string` as argument and write it as a whole into file, while `file.writelines()` takes `list of strings` as argument and write it to file. Then here is my test:

```
file_name = "employees"
content = "this is first employee\nthis is second employee\nthis is thirdemployee\n"


def write_lines(name: str, lines: list) -> None:
    with open(name, "w") as file:
        file.writelines(lines)


def read(name: str) -> None:
    with open(name) as file:
        print(file.read())


write_lines(file_name, content)
read(file_name)
```

surprisingly, it runs successfully and here is the result

```
this is first employee
this is second employee
this is thirdemployee
```

the result is actually the same as using file.write(). so, what's the difference between `file.write()` and `file.writelines()`? am I right on the previous understanding?

Comment: It works with a `str` because `iter(str)` still yields a secuence of `str` (consisting of a single character each).

Answer (score 3):

It is exactly as you have already noticed :) file.write() writes a single line to a file, file.writelines() takes a sequence of lines, and adds them to the bottom of the file.

This way Python supports Developers in coding different ways of file handling. If you want to add a whole output to a file, like an xml, you have another case as if you would simply add a line to a .csv file for example.

Let's say, you have a txt file with already 10 Lines in it. Using `.writelines()` you would add them like so:

```
    seq = ["This is 11th line\n", "This is 12th line"]
    #Write sequence of lines at the end of the file.
    fo.seek(0, 2)
    line = fo.writelines( seq )
```

If you have the case, you simply would like to add 10 lines to a file, using file.write, you would implement it like so:

```
    for i in range(10):
        f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
```